# Manipulate data in Awk

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

I am new to Awk programming.I have a question on manipulating text file,which is required to draw certain Network based images in a visualization software(Circos http://circos.ca)

I have input data for which I want to manipulate values using awk/grep/sed.
There are 9 pairs(18 lines).5 pairs(first 10 lines) are for "from=ABCB11", and 4 pairs(next 8 lines) are for "from =ABCC8". What I want is extract the value from the first line of the first pair and replace it in each alternate line of the rest of the other pairs.
So value for group-2 is 9 10 ,which should replace all the occurence of value in group2.
The next value for group-2 is 28 29,which should be replaced by 9 10.

The stop should be determined by "from=name" which is "from=ABCB11".Its not necessary that the rows that have to captured expression from and replace in its next occurence will belong to group-2 as in this instance.It could be group-3 or group-4 until group-10.So second set ("from =ABCC8")could have been belonged to group-4/5/6 not necessary group-2.Its just a coincidence here.

```
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 28 29 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-5 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-2 29 30 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-5 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-2 10 11 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-3 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-2 11 12 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-3 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 12 13 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-1 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-2 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-1 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-2 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
group-1 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
```

Below is the FINAL output,I am looking for:

```
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-5 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-5 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-3 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-3 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 12 13 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-1 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-1 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
group-1 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
```

Also,this is just a sample data.So many pairs would have group-1,group-4,group-5 upto group 10.Here,only pairs from lesser groups are mentioned.

I want to loop through the lines until the value in "from=name" remains same,so that I can change all occurences in each alternate line.Code:

```
awk -F, 'NR%2==1 {split($2,a,"="); print a[2]}' file.txt
```

The above code is able to extract the alternate lines and the "name" in "from=name"

Comment: Please show what you've tried, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: How do the groups match up? What criteria control where the first set of group-2 numbers stop and the second set of group-2 numbers start?

Comment: The stop should be determined by "from=name" which is "from=ABCB11".Its not necessary that the rows that have to captured expression from and replace in its next occurence will belong to group-2.It could be group-3 or group-4 until group-10.So second set could have been belonged to group-4/5/6 not necessary group-2.Its just a coincidence here.

Comment: I suggest you revise your question to be less "noisy", include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as all relevant explanation in the question itself, not in a comment.

Comment: I have included all the relevant explanation,but since I am new to awk programming,and it does not look to be simple parsing problem.I am working on how to loop until a certain value and replace the related occurrence but finding it tricky.

Comment: You write, that the values of "alternate lines" needs to be changed. Is this specifically
"all uneven lines of a block need to get the value of the first line, regardless of the <group-x> they belong to"
or is this more a
"all lines having the same <group-x> as the first line in a block get the same value as the first line"?

Answer (score 0):

The following is quite verbose (I love verbose variable names). Using your sample-data, I get the data you want to have. This assumes, that every "uneven" line gets the values from the first line with the same "from=xxxx" information.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    namevar=""
    val1var=""
    val2var=""
    linenum=0
  }
  {
    split($0, linearr)
    split(linearr[5], csvarr, ",")
    if (namevar != csvarr[2]) {
      namevar=csvarr[2]
      val1var=linearr[2]
      val2var=linearr[3]
      linenum=0
    }
    linenum+=1
    if (linenum%2==1) {
      print linearr[1], val1var, val2var, linearr[4], linearr[5]
    } else {
      print linearr[1], linearr[2], linearr[3], linearr[4], linearr[5]
    }
  }' file.txt
```